# how mapping text separated by a character in elasticsearch?

Tags: string, filter, elasticsearch, mapping

I will like to create a mapping for a string to analyze only string separate by ":".

For example my string "ANTENAS:Man #47:Man #20", and i want to analyze only the exact text separated by ":" --> "ANTENAS","Man #47","Man #20"

Thanks a lot !
pd.In very newbie in elasticsearch

Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mapping for that index and type you need to create a custom tokenizer that should be able to tokenize your field values based on ":" character because characters like that will be discarded by the standard analyzer.

So, the mapping should look like this for a field called "name":

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_dash_analyzer": {
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "my_custom_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_custom_tokenizer":{
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": ":"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "publication": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_dash_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now i have all string analize and divided by ":" pattern.